# Measuring audio amplifier performance

Tags: amplifier, measurement

I have a car audio system which has started to output less powerful bass. I want to quantify my observations by taking some measurements.

Doing some research, a common way to test the amplifier performance is to connect a load resistor instead of a woofer, input a sine wave and measure the output voltage. Then P=VI and you can work out the power of the output.

However, I don't believe this is a fair test. Low frequency signals consume a lot more power than higher frequency power, as does different woofer designs, and by using a static load resistor I don't see how I can measure the performance of the amplifier and to see if there's something wrong. It seems similar to running a motor with no load.

What would be a better way to test the amplifier performance? My theory is if frequency response without a load and with a load are the same, my amplifier is working fine.

Comment: A resistor is a load. The only difference is that it turns the signal into heat instead of sound. As far as the amplifier itself is concerned, there's no difference.

Comment: @tgun926: Low frequency signals don't consume more power than high frequency signals.  Most people have humongous woofers with large amplifiers driving them, so they have the impression that bass takes more power.  It doesn't.  People just make it louder.  A 100 Hz signal and a 10kHz signal will provide the same power in to the same load when at the same amplitude.

Comment: Another thing that goes into it is that ears don't work well at low frequencies.  To get the same apparent loudness at low frequencies as at higher fequencies, the low frequencies have to be produced at a higher volume - higher amplitude, more power.

Comment: In other words, testing an audio amplifier with a resistor load is a valid thing to do.

Comment: First check bass, treble, balance, fader and EQ settings. Then check speakers for damage and wiring and connectors for bad contacts and corrosion. A resistor is a load but a speaker is a resistor plus inductor unless it has something like passive crossovers or filters so impedance will vary according to frequency.

Comment: @JRE thanks for your comments. Are you saying if I play a 50HZ signal through a woofer in 'free air' i.e. no enclosure versus I physically push the woofer voice coil back so it can't move, the power in these two scenario's should be the same?

Comment: The power in those scenarios will be different.  One is a dead short, the other isn't.  If you measure the voltage across the speaker during the two events, then you will find it to be very different.  This has nothing to do with "low frequencies requiring more power" or with the validity of using a resistor to test an amplifier.